# Deciphering Type Explanations in F#

Tags: f#

I often see notation like the following in the book I am reading:

> int -> int -> int * int

Apparently it is the **type** of something.

Is there a guide anywhere to explain how to read that? It's just ints and arrows to me.

Comment: Which book are you reading? If you read [Programming F#](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-F-3-0-Chris-Smith/dp/1449320295/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1395705960&sr=8-1&keywords=programming+f%23), he explains the notion of currying and of tupples. These are the two concepts represented in your notation.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens I'm reading Beginning F#. I should clarify that it is the notation with the arrows that I don't understand. I know of tuples and that they are displayed with an asterisk. Cheers.

Comment: Good clarification, then what you want to know is about currying. The thing to realize is that in F# every function takes exactly one argument and returns exactly one value. In this case, the input argument is an int and the return value is a function which takes an int and returns a tuple.

Comment: Currying is this pattern of returning a function which takes the next argument.

Comment: These links might help: [How types work with functions](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/how-types-work-with-functions/) and more generally, a series of posts on [thinking functionally](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/thinking-functionally.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function definition in F# has roughly the following grammar

```
[parameter] -> [return type]
```

Lets use this grammar to break down the definition into pieces

```
int -> int -> int * int
```

In this case the parameter type is `int` and the return type is `int -> int * int`.  Still a strange type so lets analyze it

```
int -> int * int
```

This is a function which takes an `int` and returns `int * int`.  The `*` notation is used to indicate a tuple.  In this case a tuple with 2 members, both types being `int`.

So in summary it is a function which takes an `int` parameter and returns a function which takes an `int` parameter and returns a 2 member tuple of `int` values

Comment: i.e. `Func<int, Func<int, Tuple<int,int>>`?

Comment: @JaredPar I thought it was a function with 2 parameters which returns an int tuple. I just don't understand why a function with 2 parameters is represented by int -> int -> ...

Comment: @onefootswill F# is flexibly and will allow you to treat it either way.  If you pass one parameter it will return a function, if you pass two it will return a tuple

Answer (score 8):

As Jared says, the `int -> int -> int * int` type can be read as a function that returns a function (taking int and returning a tuple). You can add parentheses and read this as `int -> (int -> int * int)`

A function returning a function sounds a bit confusing and not very useful. But this is actually not the case in F#, because most of the time, you can read this just as a function that takes two `int` values as arguments and returns a pair of `int` values.

For example, the a function that performs division with a remainder has this type:

```
let divRem a b = (a/b, a%b)
```

Now, you can treat this as a function of two arguments and just write:

```
divRem 10 3 // returns (3, 1)
```

This is probably the more common situation. But you can also treat it as a function that returns function and call it with a single argument only:

```
let f = divRem 10
f 2  // returns (5, 0)
f 3  // returns (3, 1)
f 4  // returns (2, 2)
```

The nice thing about this is that you can then easily call the returned function with multiple different values as the second argument. So, because F# separates parameters by a space, there is smaller distinction between the two cases. In fact, you can read `divRem 10 3` as `(divRem 10) 3`.

In practice, this is really nice when working with collections. Say you want to get the results of dividing 10 by all numbers from 1 to 9. You can write just:

```
[ 1 .. 9 ] |> List.map (divRem 10)
```

Comment: Are you sure about let f = divRem 10 3 . That does not compile for me. Did you mean to curry it? e.g. let f = divRem 10

Comment: @onefootswill Yes, exactly that's what I wanted to write! Thanks :-).

Comment: @onefootswill: Also note that in the last example there are two instances of partial application: `(divRem 10)` and `List.map (divRem 10)`, which is then applied to `[1..9]` (at least conceptually).

Comment: @Frank Cool. Thanks for that. Piped forward. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

In F#, there are two ways to give a function more than argument. Let's see this for a function that just adds two numbers.

```
 let f1 (x,y) = x + y       // f1 : int * int -> int
```

This first way looks like many other languages, but in F#, we consider `f1` a function of *one* argument, which happens to be a pair of two things. Hence the type `int * int -> int`, which you read "given an `int * int`, I'll return an `int`".

```
 let f2 x y = x + y         // f2 : int -> int -> int
```

This second way is the one with the many arrows. `f2` is still a function of two things, but now we give it those two things one at a time:

```
 let x = f2 10 5           // x = 15 : int

 let g = f 10              // g : int -> int
 let y = g 5               // y = 15 : int
```

This is indicated by the arrows. Technically, we should read the type "int -> int -> int" as "given an int, I'll return (a function which given an int returns an int)". Or more straightforwardly, "given an int, and thereafter another int, I'll return an int".

As Tomas points out, this is often convenient if you want to, say, add 10 to every number in a list:

```
List.map (f2 10) [3; 5; 7; 11]        // = [13; 15; 17; 21]
```

It's a famous result of computer science that the type `int -> int -> int` is just a different (but more flexible) way of writing the type `int * int -> int`. We can even write functions to convert between them:

```
let curry   f  x y  = f (x,y)
let uncurry f (x,y) = f  x y
```

With these functions we have `curry f1` = `f2` and `uncurry f2` = `f1`.

Comment: Would you explain how your curry function is a form of currying?

Comment: "Currying" means exactly taking a function that takes a tuple argument and converting it to a function that give the first component of such a tuple gives you a function waiting for the rest. But this is what `curry` does.

Comment: That is, "currying" is to take a function of type `'a * 'b -> 'c` and convert it to a function `'a -> 'b -> 'c` which accepts the tuple components "one at a time", but otherwise does the same thing as the original function.

Answer (score 1):

You might prefer conventional mathematical notation:

```
ℤ → (ℤ → ℤ×ℤ)
```

It means a function that takes an integer and returns a function that takes another integer and returns a pair of integers.

FWIW, I describe the syntax in detail in all of my books and tutorial courses.

Comment: Thanks Jon. That's really cool. I may have to seek out one of those books. Cheers!